# ASP.NET Web API role based security

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api

I have created an asp.net odata web api project that uses an entity framework database. This is nothing special, many tutorials take this approach. I have secured this api with users and roles so only administrators can actually save something using the web api.

My next step would be to make some information only accessible for specific roles. If I, for example, would have an entity Employee with a Salary property. Then how would I restrict (read) access to this property only to Administrators?

**Edit**

I'll try to specify my question.
Given the following controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable<Employee> Get()
    {
        return _Db.Employees;
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to write odata querys aqainst this e.g `http://api.com/employee?$select=FirstName,LastName,Salary&$orderby=Salary`

If I don't want certain people (or roles) to order by salary I can implement an [OrderByQueryValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.validators.orderbyqueryvalidator%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).
But how can I completely hide the Salary property for normal users while still allowing administrators to select it?

So, given the controller above, I want the administrators to be able execute both these:

```
http://api.com/employee?$select=FirstName,LastName,Salary&$orderby=Salary
http://api.com/employee?$select=FirstName,LastName&$orderby=FirstName
```

while normal users will only be able execute this:

```
http://api.com/employee?$select=FirstName,LastName&$orderby=FirstName
```

and get an error when trying to select the Salary property.

Comment: That's what you got setters and getters for.

Comment: If I were to use a getter for this situation, I still have to return a default value (or null). Then in my json or xml response I get the property with the default value. That does not seem right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ViewModel approach. Instead of giving the Employee object, creating a new class named EmployeeViewModel and create the properties you would like to share. I recommend also creating a static method to create a ViewModel from the Model and vice-versa.

Comment: Despite the restrictions @dave refers to in his answer, I like the approach of ViewModels. However, I'm not sure where this fits in. My controllers return generic IQueryable and then some of my Entity Framework classes. This way I'm able to leverage the benefits of OData, like $select and $expand. So using the ViewModels probably means I have to implement a lot of the OData stuff myself?

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom authorization is always an interesting part of projects. The most flexible/cleanest way I have implemented it was with aspects. 
We used [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), and we simply created a RequirePermission attribute, that could be applied to any methods. 
The attribute had a parameter that contained the permission, that was required to execute the method. For example: RequirePermission(Permission="ReadSalary").
You can decide it in the attribute what to do when the user doesn't have the required permission. Either throw an exception, or simply skip method execution.

You could reach the same behaviour without aspects, but you will probably write more code, and I find it much cleaner to be solved with aspects.

A quicker and easier way might be to have different ViewModels for different roles, but I would only advice to use something like this if you are sure to keep the number of roles (like admin and user) low. The you could have a EmployeeSummary and an EmployeeDetails view model, and simple give back the right one based on the current user's role.